# LISP - Write the function (REMOVE EL), that removes given atom or list from another list on all levels of the list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have the following task:

To build the function (REMOVE EL), that removes given atom or list from another list, and this should apply on each level of the list

Example :

```
L=(A B A (B A C X ) X B)
(REMOVE A L ) -> (B (B C X) X B)
```

I wrote the following code :

```
(defun removeel(el tree)
  (mapcan (lambda(subtree)
            (cond ((null subtree) (list nil))
                  ((consp subtree) (list (removeel el subtree)))
                  ((eql subtree el) nil)
                  (t (list subtree))))
          tree))
```

The problem is that when I remove atom, it works excellent

```
(removeel 'B' (A B A (B A C X ) X B))
 (A A (A C X) X)
```

But it doesn't work If I want to remove a list

```
(removeel '(B A C X) ' (A B A (B A C X ) X B))
  (A B A (B A C X) X B)
```

What should be done to make it to remove lists too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simplest way would be to introduce optional equality test function, as in `remove` standard procedure.

it could look this way:

```
(defun rem-rec (item data &key (test #'eql))
  (mapcar (lambda (x) (if (listp x)
                          (rem-rec item x :test test)
                          x))
      (remove item data :test test)))

CL-USER> (rem-rec 1 `(1 2 (3 4 (1 2 3)) (1 (1 2 3) 3 4)))
;;=> (2 (3 4 (2 3)) ((2 3) 3 4))
```

for lists equality you can use `equal` (or `equalp` or anything more specific)

```
CL-USER> (rem-rec '(1 2 3) '(1 2 (3 4 (1 2 3)) (1 (1 2 3) 3 4)) :test #'equal)
;;=> (1 2 (3 4) (1 3 4))
```

Comment: but is there any solution to do this without this test function ?

Comment: Well, if you replace the ’eq' in your code with 'equal', it should work both for atoms and lists

Comment: But the test function is the common standard library idiom, also it could allow you to do more complicated actions, like for example removing all lists of length n, or whatever else you want

Comment: I have rearranged a little the conditions 

`(defun removeel(el tree)
  (mapcan (lambda(subtree)
            (cond ((null subtree) (list nil))
     ((equal subtree el) nil)
                  ((consp subtree) (list (removeel el subtree)))
                  (t (list subtree))))
          tree))`

And changed eql to equal. Now everything works fine

Thanks for your help ;)